# Trying to use strtok to separate string from a file and store in structure array

Tags: c, struct, structure, void, strtok

i've written the code below:

```
struct customer {
    char name[30]
    int age, phoneNo;
    struct address {
        int houseNumber;
    } homeAddress;
};


void search()
{
    char search[50];
    char record[100];
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char* pStr;
    struct customer c;

    FILE* fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("customer.txt", "r");
    // flag to check whether record found or not
    int foundRecord = 0;
    printf("Enter name to search : ");
    // fgets gets name to search
    scanf("%s", search);
    //remove the '\n' at the end of string

    while (fgets(record, 100, fPtr))
    {
        // strstr returns start address of substring in case if present
        if (strstr(record, search))
        {
            char* pStr = strtok(record, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.name, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.age = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.phoneNo = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.homeAddress.houseNumber = atoi(pStr);
            }
            foundRecord = 1;
            printf("Your details: ");
            printf("%s, %d, %d, %d\n", c.name, c.age, c.phoneNo, c.homeAddress.houseNumber);
        }
        if (!foundRecord)
            printf("%s cannot be found\n", search);
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
}
```

When I call for the void search function in my main, the code isn't working well (i can't input anything to search and i get a bunch of symbols that don't make sense). Basically, I have a struct called customer, I made it a struct array, and I am trying to input a customer's details such as their name, to search for their details, store it into the struct array, and display it. The customer details are stored in a text file like below:

```
John Doe,10,123456789,5,Streets,Paris,P,60393
Mary Ann,39,12935837,5,Streetss,Cities,C,48354
```

May I know how I can fix my code so that it works?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show us a [mcve]. The first part looks like you're mixing `scanf` and `fgets`. The second problem is that you read into `d[1]` and then print both `d[0]` (which is uninitialized) and `d[1]`.

Comment: When you return from `search()` the array `struct customer d[200];` will vanish. You seem to be mixing a data load with a search. if you load the data first, you can then do searches in the array.

Comment: Actually you don't need the `d` array at all, just a single `struct customer` variable. Once a match is found you can just leave the function (once you read and printed the *single* `customer` structure).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude hi, thank you for the advice. i've change the array into simply a struct now. after changing fgets to scanf in the first part, i am able to input a name and search. however, i'm not sure how to change the fgets in my while loop. how do i make my fPtr progress through each record in my while test expression?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry i'm not quite sure what you meant by "loading the data first". how do i accomplish this?

Comment: You should still use `fgets` to read input from the *file*. Mixing `scanf` and `fgets` is only troublesome if you use it on the same source stream.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude i've edited the code here into what i have now (minus some variables in the struct). hope it makes sense. and thanks for explaining the reason behind fgets :)

Comment: hi @user3121023, this question was solved. it turns out one of my data was not scanned into the textfile during input, hence when i printed the output, it couldn't find the string and printed out a bunch of characters. it's purely my fault. thank you for the help though! have a nice day :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on how the function could work without the array, it could look something like:

```
void search()
{
    char search[30];  // Match the length of the name in the structure
    char record[100];
    struct customer c;

    FILE* fPtr;
    fPtr = fopen("customer.txt", "r");
    // TODO: Should really check for failure here

    printf("Enter name to search : ");
    scanf(" %29[^\n]", search);  // Read at most 29 characters, plus the string terminator makes 30

    // Read lines from the file
    while (fgets(record, sizeof record, fPtr))
    {
        // strstr returns start address of substring in case if present
        if (strstr(record, search))
        {
            // Found the record we're searching for

            char* pStr = strtok(record, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                strcpy(c.name, pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.age = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.phoneNo = atoi(pStr);
            }
            pStr = strtok(NULL, ",");
            if (pStr != NULL) {
                c.homeAddress.houseNumber = atoi(pStr);
            }

            printf("Your details: ");
            printf("%s, %d, %d, %d\n", c.name, c.age, c.phoneNo, c.homeAddress.houseNumber);

            // There's no need to read more data from the file
            // So break out of the loop
            break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fPtr);
}
```

Comment: thank you. i've modified my code to match this, but when i run it, not only is it printing out the record i'm looking for, but also a bunch of symbols that don't make sense at the end. may i know how i can fix it?

Comment: and when i run it a few times, it says the "stack around variable c is corrupted"...

Comment: @cmy There's no "name" in the file that's longer than 29 characters?

Comment: no, i only have two names: John Doe and Mary Ann, in the text file, to test out the code

Comment: @cmy The only place in my function which could lead to such problems is `strcpy(c.name, pStr)`, and that should only happens if the string in `pStr` happens to be longer than 29 characters (plus null-terminator). Otherwise I have capped the input for `search`, and using the correct size for `fgets` should not lead it to go out of bounds either.

Comment: i noticed that the number of characters changes when i change the size of of fgets in the while loop. when it put the size of as 100, the entire record of John Doe gets printed out + a bunch of symbols, but when i put the size of as 50, the zipCode isn't printed out, although the bunch of symbols continue to be printed at the end

Comment: @cmy If you have only some short test-data in the file, please copy-paste it *verbatim*, in full and complete, into the question.

Comment: i've edited the question to include the two strings of data i have in the file. hope it helps

Comment: it's printing this when i search for John Doe: Your details: John Doe, 10, 123456789, 5, Streets, Paris, P, 60393
, ╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠╠

Comment: when i use `scanf("%29[^\n]", search);` and run the code, it does not let me input at all :(

Comment: hi. i've found the mistake, it was a problem in my input (i have another function where i am inputting the data into the text file, and i did not scanf for the last input (c.history), so when i searched for it, it ended up printing a bunch of symbols because it could not find (c.history) in the text file. i'm so sorry for the trouble, it turns out it was my mistake orz. thank you so much for the help! i really appreciate it, have a nice day! :)